# A master/slave panel in Extjs 5 MVC

Tags: forms, extjs, model-view-controller, master-slave

I'm using Extjs5.1 powered by a MVC oriented code style.
I've got a main view which inherits from Ext.panel.Panel with a border layout.

- On the east region, there's a grid with a store containing several records (or "models", I don't really know what terminology I should use here).  (the "master grid")
- On the center region, there is another view that inherits from a Ext.form.Panel and which is supposed to display the selected item of the grid .  (the "slave form")

My goal is to refresh the "slave form" with the selected record of the "master grid".

The only way I found to "communicate" between the grid and the form is to execute a fireEvent('selectRecord', ...) from the main view controller and to listen to him inside the form view controller, but it seems odd as the form view is a child item of the main view.

Is there a more common way to do that?

By corrolary, is it a fine practice to make a view call functions of another view directly or should I make only their respective controllers interact?

Comment: Have a look at this example http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/grid/binding.html
How you end up referencing the components is quite up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do and I believe is the most common approach for this, is having a selectionchange event listener, that updates your form like this:

```
listeners : {
    selectionchange: function(model, records) {
        var rec = records[0];
        if (rec) {
            formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
        }
    }
}
```

for this to work, the `name` property of your form fields must match the name of the fields in the grid store model.

There is an example of this here: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-grid

Comment: Thanks. My problem is mainly to know if it's not a bad practice to access another view directly instead of using its controller.

Comment: You should use the grid controller to listen to the selectionchange event, there is no need to use the form panel's controller. I created this fiddle using a viewcontroller so you have an idea https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gn0